# Java Web Start Crashes After Splash Screen

Tags: windows-7, java, jnlp

I am working with JNLP and I'm unable to launch Java Web Start. The issue is specific to my machine. I am able to launch it on other PC's without any issues.

When I launch the JNLP the Java Web Start splash screen appears for a few seconds then disappears. The Java Console is set to Show but does not appear. In Task Manager the javaws.exe and jp2launcher.exe appear while the splash screen is open then terminate.

My machine:
Windows 7 Pro 64
Java 8 Update 60 (Have also tried Java 8 Update 51)

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Further diagnostic suggestions: Uninstall all versions of Java, reboot, install latest/desired Java version, try it again. If it still doesn't work, create a new user, log in that user, and see if it works for them.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 I followed all of the suggestions your recommended. What did work was creating a new user on my PC. They are able to launch JWS. I went back to my account and it continued to not work. I did notice that when I uninstalled/reinstalled, my Java settings like "show console" and the exceptions list were still present. Is there a way to fully remove all Java settings? TIA

Answer (score 3):

Because the issue was specific to my user profile on Windows, the fix was to...

1. Uninstall all versions of Java.
2. Delete C:\Users\\AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java
3. Delete C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\Sun\Java
4. Reboot
5. Reinstall Java JRE or JDK

Answer (score 1):

We had same issue of launching JNLP and the J2PLauncher process would exit.
It seems to happen only when opening a JNLP file from a network location. if we copy the JNLP file to our local drive and run then the application starts normally.